# Async sends in .NET ActiveMQ

Tags: performance, asynchronous, activemq-classic, blocking, throughput

I'm looking to increase the performance of a high-throughput producer that I'm writing against ActiveMQ, and according to [this](http://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri.html) useAsyncSend will:

> Forces the use of Async Sends which adds a massive performance boost;
>   but means that the send() method will return immediately whether the
>   message has been sent or not which could lead to message loss.

However I can't see it making any difference to my simple test case.

Using this very basic application:

```
const string QueueName = "....";
const string Uri = "....";

static readonly Stopwatch TotalRuntime = new Stopwatch();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TotalRuntime.Start();
    SendMessage();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void SendMessage()
{
    var session = CreateSession();
    var destination = session.GetQueue(QueueName);
    var producer = session.CreateProducer(destination);

    Console.WriteLine("Ready to send 700 messages");
    Console.ReadLine();

    var body = new byte[600*1024];

    Parallel.For(0, 700, i => SendMessage(producer, i, body, session));         
}

static void SendMessage(IMessageProducer producer, int i, byte[] body, ISession session)
{
     var message = session.CreateBytesMessage(body);

     var sw = new Stopwatch();
     sw.Start();
     producer.Send(message);
     sw.Stop();

     Console.WriteLine("Running for {0}ms: Sent message {1} blocked for {2}ms", 
            TotalRuntime.ElapsedMilliseconds, 
            i, 
            sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}       

static ISession CreateSession()
{
     var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(Uri)
                                    {
                                        AsyncSend = true,
                                        CopyMessageOnSend = false
                                    };
     var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
     connection.Start();
     var session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);
     return session;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Ready to send 700 messages

Running for 2430ms: Sent message 696 blocked for 12ms
Running for 4275ms: Sent message 348 blocked for 1858ms
Running for 5106ms: Sent message 609 blocked for 2689ms
Running for 5924ms: Sent message 1 blocked for 2535ms
Running for 6749ms: Sent message 88 blocked for 1860ms
Running for 7537ms: Sent message 610 blocked for 2429ms
Running for 8340ms: Sent message 175 blocked for 2451ms
Running for 9163ms: Sent message 89 blocked for 2413ms
.....
```

Which shows that each message takes about 800ms to send and the call to `session.Send()` blocks for about two and a half seconds. Even though the documentation says that

> "send() method will return immediately"

Also these number are basically the same if I either change the parallel for to a normal for loop or change the `AsyncSend = true` to `AlwaysSyncSend = true` so I don't believe that the async switch is working at all...

Can anyone see what I'm missing here to make the send asynchronous?

---

After further testing:

According to ANTS performance profiler that vast majority of the runtime is being spent waiting for synchronization. It appears that the issue is that the various transport classes block internally through monitors. In particular I seem to get hung up on the [MutexTransport](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/activemq/activemq-dotnet/Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ/tags/1.5.6/src/main/csharp/Transport/MutexTransport.cs?view=markup)'s OneWay method which only allows one thread to access it at a time.

It looks as though the call to Send will block until the previous message has completed, this explains why my output shows that the first message blocked for 12ms, while the next took 1858ms. I can have multiple transports by implementing a connection-per-message pattern which improves matters and makes the message sends work in parallel, but greatly increases the time to send a single message, and uses up so many resources that it doesn't seem like the right solution.

I've retested all of this with 1.5.6 and haven't seen any difference.

Comment: Some critical information missing here, what versions of NMS.ActiveMQ?  What is the actual URI you pass to connect to the broker?  Does the broker have any producer flow control enabled?

Comment: @Tim Good points, sorry. I'm running version 1.5.1, the URI is an internal server, but is of the form "tcp://..." and I don't know anything about how the broker is set up - I have access to the console webpage, but that doesn't appear to expose that information. Further investigation has led me to believe that the issue is with the size of the message I'm sending (600Kb) but I'm still looking into it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As always the best thing to do is update to the latest version (1.5.6 at the time of this writing).  A send can block if the broker has producer flow control enabled and you've reached a queue size limit although with async send this shouldn't happen unless you are sending with a producerWindowSize set.  One good way to get help is to create a test case and submit it via a Jira issue to the NMS.ActiveMQ site so that we can look into it using your test code.  There have been many fixes since 1.5.1 so I'd recommend giving that new version a try as it could already be a non-issue.